# Find position of tags in string

Tags: c#

I have a string like :

```
<table><tr><td>This is my string <img width="100" height="10" src="images/image.jpg"></td></tr></table>
```

I want to find the position of the `<img` tag and the position of the end of the image tag. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you need to accept any arbitrary HTML, or some very limited set of it?  If you need true HTML support [you won't be able to use regular expressions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1732348%2Fregex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags&ei=OGsRUOWTDKeS6wG644HQDg&usg=AFQjCNFUiiPiThKTDTpEvIeZ7Sn3hPF_3A).  (Using something like `indexOf` has the exact same problems.)

Comment: @Servy I need to know the start of the <img tag and the end of the img tag.

Comment: @Justin That doesn't answer my question at all.  It just re-states part of what you already said in your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with IndexOf in your string, example:

```
int position = yourString.IndexOf('test');
```